# If $0\leq d\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is the identity or is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: field-theory

If $0\leq d\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is the identity or is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

According to the definition $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) = \lbrace{\sigma\in Aut( \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})) : \sigma |_\mathbb{Q} = id_\mathbb{Q}\rbrace}$. So the first case is concluded by definition.

I can only think of one way to approach the case where it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and that is to use the fact that a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $\lbrace{1,\sqrt{d}\rbrace}$. Where to go from here is unclear.

Comment: The extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})/\Bbb Q$ is Galois, so that the order of the group is the field degree $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d}):\Bbb Q]$ - which is $1$ or $2$.

Comment: What is $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ in relation to the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q}$? Or where can I read more about this?

Comment: You have to distinguish the case where $d= q^2$ for some rational number $q$ and the case where this is not true. In the second case, write down the minimal polynomial of $d$, which will be of degree 2. Can you think of an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ which leaves $\mathbb{Q}$ fixed but permutes the zeros of that minimal polynomial?

Comment: @Thomas for the second case, the minimal polynomial would be $f(x) = x^{2} - d$ correct? But I'm drawing a blank on coming up with such an automorphism.

Comment: switch the roots of the minimal polynomial

Comment: @Thomas I see now. I need to work on this for a little bit, but I will come back with more questions and perhaps an attempted proof.